# Determine the values of $p>0$ for which the improper integral $ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^p \sqrt{1+x^p}} $ converges.

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Determine the values of $p>0$ for which the improper integral 
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^p \sqrt{1+x^p}}
$$
converges. I know that
$$
\frac{1}{x^p \sqrt{1+x^p}} \leq \frac{1}{x^p},
$$
so 
$$
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^p \sqrt{1+x^p}}
$$
converges for $p>1$ and
$$
\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^p \sqrt{1+x^p}}
$$
converges for $p<1$.

After that I am stuck.

Comment: The integral from $1$ to $\infty$ converges when $\frac{3p}{2}\gt 1$.

Comment: @graydad  the limits are from 0 to 1

Comment: Letting $t=\dfrac1{1+x^p}$ , this becomes the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral from $1$ to $\infty$ converges when $\frac{3p}{2}\gt 1$, and diverges otherwise.  This can be done by limit comparison with $\frac{1}{x^{3p/2}}$.

So we want $p\gt \frac{2}{3}$. As you pointed out, the integral  from $0$ to $1$ converges if $p\lt 1$. It diverges for $p\ge 1$. This is because on $(0,1]$ we have $\frac{1}{x^p\sqrt{1+x^p}}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}x^p}$.

So we have convergence of **both** integrals precisely if $\frac{2}{3}\lt p\lt 1$.

Comment: How do I know that the integral does not converge for other values of p?

Comment: The full integral converges iff the two integrals $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $\infty$ **both** converge. You know that $\int_0^1$ converges for $p\lt 1$. It should be clear that it diverges if $p\ge 1$, for on $(0,1)$ we have that our function is $\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}x^p}$. Also, by limit comparison $\int_1^\infty$ converges iff $p\gt \frac{2}{3}$. Put the two together.

Comment: We were (in this case) neither mixed up. On $(0,1]$, we have $\sqrt{1+x^p}\le \sqrt{2}$, so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^p}}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Ok I see now.  Although I am still a little confused how you can extend the limit comparison test to integration, since all the sources I have found indicate that the limit comparison test is used for sequences.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Comment: If you don't like limit comparison, inequalities will often work. For example, for the integral from $1$ to infinity, let $p\le 2/3$. Then our function is $\ge \frac{1}{x^p\sqrt{x^p+x^p}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}x^{3p/2}}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}x}$ so we have divergence.

Comment: I see how you can use limit comparison test now, just combine it with the integral test

Comment: We are using standard facts about $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^q}\,dx$ and the same for $1$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

At $x = 0$ there is a vertical asymptote, so you need to split the integral in two:
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^p \sqrt{1+x^p}} = \int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^p \sqrt{1+x^p}} + \int_1^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^p \sqrt{1+x^p}}$$

Let's denote by $f(x)$ the function you want to integrate. We'll use twice the asymptotic comparison test for improper integrals. It states that a function has the same behaviour as its principal part.

For $x \to 0$ you have that
$$f(x)\sim\frac1{x^p\left(1 + \frac12x^p\right)}\sim\frac1{x^p}$$
and thus the first integral converges *only* if $p < 1$.
For $x \to +\infty$ we have instead
$$f(x) = \frac1{x^px^{p/2}\left(1 + \frac1{x^p}\right)}\sim\frac1{x^{3p/2}}$$
Hence the second integral converges *only* if $\frac{3p}2 > 1 \implies p > \frac23$.

Therefore we have convergence of both integrals for $\frac23 < p < 1$.